# How can I make a degree symbol on an axis label of my MatLab graph?

Tags: matlab

I am currently using this-> ylabel('Temperature (degrees C)')
but I want to change the word degrees into its symbol to make the label shorter in length.

Comment: Are you sure that is an electrical engineering question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering.

Comment: try copying it from the internet ... https://www.degreesymbol.net/

Comment: I just want to let you know that I am asking this question for a graph I am making for my ECE class. I am processing and representing data in MatLab being read from an Arduino

Comment: ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° ° here are a few - let me know when you run out of them.

Answer (score 2):

On the PC platform you can type \$\text{<Alt>}\$0176 (on the numeric keyboard only).

It may or may not render  properly but it should work for the default settings.

Comment: Shouldn't it be **Alt** + 0 1 7 6 (on the num. keypad)?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes, it should be. The '<',' >', and contents were eaten up as some kind of markup.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab supports some \$\LaTeX\$ in legends, labels, and titles.  So `ylabel('$ ^\circ \mathrm{C}$')` should show just the degrees C part.

With luck, `ylabel('Temperature $^\circ \mathrm{C}$')` should work.  It should roughly render as "Temperature \$^\circ \mathrm{C}\$".  If it doesn't, dive into the Matlab documentation and see if you can make it work.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21984-tex-latex-math-mode-symbols-in-legends-and-labels-in-matlab-figures

Comment: Well it doesn't work but I'll look into the documentation you linked

Comment: By default axis labels and titles use a subset of Latex, so you don't need the $ to specify inline formatting, just the \circ. See the "interpreter" section of the help page at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html

Comment: @BroomHilda if you try Austin's change and it works, let me know and I'll edit my answer.